# VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument error and webcam selected

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, camera, webcam

I am using the following code to read data from a firewire Cam I have connected to my system

```
    #include "/home/iiith/opencv-2.4.9/include/opencv/cv.h"
    #include "/home/iiith/opencv-2.4.9/include/opencv/highgui.h"
    #include "cxcore.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main(int,char**)
    {
         VideoCapture cap(0);
         if(!cap.isOpened())
             cout<<"Camera not detected"<<endl;
         while(1)
         {
              Mat frame;
              namedWindow("display",1);
              cap >> frame;
              imshow("display",frame);
              waitKey(0);   
         }
    }
```

When I execute I get the following error

```
    VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
    VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
    VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
```

And then, my webcam fires up and video is read from there. Can you please tell me why this happens? I am using ubuntu 12.04 and opencv 2.4.9. When I tried it on my friend's system, same config and libraries, it worked perfectly without any errors. Please help me here. Have been at this over a week. Thanks in advance